# How to find what a light switch controls?

Tags: electrical, switch

I've got two switches in a house new to me that are a mystery to what they may control. Both have voltage to them. Both are two way switches. One is an interior switch that I've tried a circuit tester on outlets, all lights appear to be illuminated etc. and can't seem to figure out what it does.

The other one is part of a bank that controls exterior lights but ALL the lights are on and this 4th switch doesn't seem to do much. Any way to trace this? How do electricians trace a circuit?(some toner type equipments?)

Comment: Did you test both top and bottom of the outlets?  Some are half switched.

Comment: Re: exterior — have you looked for a Christmas light receptacle (sometimes tucked under the eaves)?

Comment: As noted in another answer recently, there are "toner" devices which can treat a wire as a broadcasting antenna, which a proximity-detecting scanner can then let you follow through the walls. This would be a more complicated use, since you'd have to dissect the switch connection first, but it is one approach. Not an especially cheap one, though unless you can borrow the device or score a working one cheap on eBay and understand how to use it.

Comment: With the switch turned off, check to see if there is full voltage on **both** wires. If so, it’s probably controlling a half-switched outlet that someone replaced and didn’t break the tab connecting the two hot terminals. Unfortunately, I don’t have a  good way to find the outlet other than checking each one.

Comment: Can't use a tone gen on a live circuit. They get another dude to turn them *back* on one at a time, and using a *contact* (!) voltage tester they verify the circuit.... *You* don't do anything.

Comment: Can you ask the sellers/old owners?